# Where can I find the contents of sys_errlist?

Tags: c, unix

sys_errlist is indexed by errno and contains the appropriate error message. Where can I see the contents of this list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably in some system header file included somehow by `<errno.h>`. If you want to print its full content you can easily do it with a small program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i=0; i<sys_nerr; i++)
        printf("sys_errlist[%d] = \"%s\"\n", i, sys_errlist[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

(`sys_nerr` is defined as the number of entries in `sys_errlist`)

Still, keep in mind that, according to my manpages, `perror` or `strerror` should be preferred since

> new error values may not have been added to `sys_errlist[]`.

Answer (score 4):

It is **deprecated**, and you should **use** [strerror](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/strerror.html)

Answer (score 1):

As

```
man sys_errlist
```

tells me:

- `sys_errlist` is the array that contains the messages
- `sys_nerr` contains the number of messages in `sys_errlist`, so you can access the messages from `0` to `sys_nerr-1`
- `sys_errlist` is **deprecated**, use `strerror()` or `strerror_r()` instead

Answer (score 1):

The actual error definitions in the headers are located in two files, /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h and /usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h

Answer (score 0):

As people already pointed out, `sys_errlist` is deprecated. As of the content of such array, which was eventually defined in errlist.c, take a look at the following links provided by woboq:

[sys_errlist.h](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/sys_errlist.h.html#27)

[errlist.c](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/errlist.c.html#_sys_errlist)