# Why is 'sys_errlist' deprecated in glibc?

Tags: c, posix, gnu, glibc, errno

`sys_errlist` is a handy array which allows getting static `errno` descriptions. The alternative to it is the `strerror_r` function, which is available in two confusing incompatible flavors. The GNU version of it returns `char *`, which would be from that same aforementioned array as long as the error is known, or otherwise from the user-supplied buffer. The standards-compliant version of `strerror_r` returns an `int` instead, and always uses the user-supplied buffer. The problem is, those two functions share the same name despite having completely different semantics, so you basically have to perform a fairly complex `#ifdef` check and write two completely different versions of your code depending on which version you get. In addition to that, both of those functions are worse than `sys_errlist`, as both require for the caller to provide a "large enough" buffer to hold the description, even though the GNU version would rarely use it, and neither function allows to know just how large the buffer should really be. If instead you choose to use `sys_errlist` instead, you can simply check whether `value >= sys_nerr` and allocate the buffer only in that case, just to put the `Unknown error %d` there via `snprintf`, and be done.

Given that `strerror_r` is a horrible, incomprehensible and inefficient mess, why did GNU developers mark `sys_errlist` as deprecated, effectively forcing one to either use `strerrror_r` or to observe the ugly warning each time the code is compiled?

Answer (score 1):

`strerror` and its relative are *localized*.  The usefulness of a non-localized system message can be debated, but glibc's maintainers went with the prevailing direction ([Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0477/6j9r2e2bq/index.html) and other systems).

However: `sys_errlist` has been deprecated for quite a while. It is not a POSIX interface.  Some systems do not have it.

Further reading:

- [Where can I find the contents of sys_errlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494383/where-can-i-find-the-contents-of-sys-errlist)
- [Use strerror() or strerror_r() instead of sys_errlist and sys_nerr](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1830) (fish-shell bug #1830)
- [RE: sys_errlist](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1999-11/msg00103.html) (Cygwin in 1999)
- [GNU Hurd/ hurd/ porting/ guidelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd/porting/guidelines.html)

It's been a while since this was an issue, but it used to be the case that some systems did not have `strerror` (see [Unix Incompatibility Notes:
String and Memory Functions](http://unixpapa.com/incnote/string.html)).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question at all. `sys_errlist` is a static array  and is completely thread safe.

Comment: There are a lot of non-standard things in glibc the usage of which doesn't seem to be accompanied with compile-time deprecation warnings

Comment: There are a *ton* of interfaces provided by Glibc that aren't POSIX-compliant, and aren't deprecated.

Comment: But there's nothing that isn't thread-safe about using `sys_errlis`.

Comment: What's funny that even now a number of builds doesn't support "new way" even while compiler nags about "old way"

Comment: and apparently strerror is not thread-safe/reentrant (more, it's broken after fork)

Comment: That (non-reentrant) is a consequence of it being localized.  You might be able to tame it using POSIX locale.  For fork - perhaps you're seeing problems with a `vfork`.